# MeshLab - TIN Upsampling

Tags: meshlab

Is it possible in MeshLab to upsample existing TIN? I know it's kind of odd question but ideally scenario is a denser TIN where extra vertexes/points are interpolated from between existing ones.
Thank you
J

Comment: Please have a look at [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and try to edit your question to provide a [mcve]. Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to upsample a [Triangulated irregular network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_irregular_network) you can use any [Subdivision Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface) available in the section `Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction`.

For example, here the result of two different subdivision schemas for this input mesh:

[image: Input mesh used as example]

After one iteration of the Midpoint Subdivision Filter, you get one new vertex in the middle of each edge, so each triangle in the original mesh is decomposed in four similar triangles. If you need to increase the density of vertex, just adjust the value of the "Iterations" parameter.

[image: After one iteration of Midpoint Subdivision Filter]

Probably this is what you are looking for if you are just starting to work in subdivision.

If you choose other [interpolate subdivision filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface#Interpolating_schemes), as [butterfly](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~niradyn/papers/butterfly.pdf), the vertex of your original mesh will be still there, but the new vertex will not be on the edges of the original mesh. This is used to enhance the C2 continuity (smoothness) of the new mesh.

[image: After two iterations of Butterfly Subdivision Filter]